# Setting the date's day / month / year to default, only care about time

Tags: java, date

I have this `Date date` input variable, how can I set date's day to 1, month to 1, and year to 1970? I need to do this because this date is being checked if it is included in a range of Date type, and the range is is checking against has the default date, 1-1-1970. So I want to just scrap the month, day, and year part of the date completely and only check the time to see if is included in the range. By setting them input date's to 1-1-1970 will bypass that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(yourDate);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1970);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
yourDate = calendar.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement, one solution would use a [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) -

```
public static Date getDate(int hh, int mm, int ss) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1970);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, hh);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mm);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, ss);
    return cal.getTime();
}

// Another approach; using epoch.
public static Date getDate2(int hh, int mm, int ss) {
    long epoch = new GregorianCalendar(1970, 0, 1).getTimeInMillis();
    long v = (ss * 1000) + (mm * 60 * 1000) + (hh * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    return new Date(epoch + v);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Date a = getDate(1, 2, 3);
    Date b = getDate2(1, 2, 3);
    // Do we get the "same" Date?
    System.out.println(a.toString().equals(b.toString()));
}
```

Output is

```
true
```